# Format a text from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have this code in MVC :

```
 <div id="weight">
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Weight, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "form-control" } })
</div>
```

On page load the weight field is `0`.

I want to format this field like : `0 g`

And after each time when I modify this field to add `g` at the end.

How can I do this from javascript?

Comment: Why do you need the `g` inside the textbox? Put it outside in `label` or `span` or something..

Comment: I need this to be inside the textbox .

Comment: Do you understand that this is annoying for the user to delete the `g` everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I think it's better to put the `g` outside this will work for you.

The logic is:

1. Get the current value.
2. Check if there are `g` in the in it.
3. If not, add it in the end.

Do this check on page shows and after the user focusout (`blur`) from the input.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
function addG() {
  var val = input.value;
  if (val.indexOf('g') == -1) {
      input.value = val + 'g';
  }
}

addG();
input.onblur = addG;
```

```html
<input type="text" value="0" />
```